# Something strange about output tensor shape of tf.data.Dataset.map()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tf.data.Dataset.map() to transform my tf.data.Dataset. When I nest output of map_func with list or tuple, the output shape changes. I don't know why and how can I control it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.constant([10,20,30])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input)
#Out: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: (), types: tf.int32>

ds1=ds.map(lambda x: [x+1, x+2, x+3])
#Out: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((), (), ()), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32)>

ds2=ds.map(lambda x: [[x+1, x+2, x+3]])
Out: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((3,),), types: (tf.int32,)>

ds3=ds.map(lambda x: ([x+1, x+2, x+3]))
#Out: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((), (), ()), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32)>

ds4=ds.map(lambda x: x+1, x+2, x+3)
#NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I expect output shape to be (3,) , neither ((), (), ()) nor ((3,),). 
Why ds1 and ds3 output ((), (), ()) while ds2 output ((3,),)?
And why ds4 trigger NameError?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow assumes that Python structures like lists or tuples returned by a mapping function represent nested tensor structures. You can make sure that the returned value is a single tensor for example like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.constant([10,20,30])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(input)
ds1 = ds.map(lambda x: tf.convert_to_tensor([x+1, x+2, x+3]))
# <MapDataset shapes: (3,), types: tf.int32>
```

Comment: In many other scenes, Tensorflow only treats tuple as nested tensor structures while treating list as tensor. e.g. `ds1=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([1,2,3], [4,5,6])) #out: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32)>` while `ds1=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]) #out: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: (3,), types: tf.int32>`. The behavior of list [] differs from map function, in which map function treats [x+1, x+2, x+3] as ((), (), ()) and [[x+1, x+2, x+3]] as ((3,), ), i.e. outsider [] is treated as tuple (). It's vague.

Comment: @Jahangir Yes, you're right about that... I think usually TF uses tuples to identify nested structures, the "top-level list" here seems to be treated differently for some reason. I'd use tuples to express nested structure and `convert_to_tensor` (or other TF operations) to express tensors, to avoid confusion. But I think an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) could be filed about this behavior.